# Programmatic way to find the Windows OS volume?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I understand it is not recommended to assume that drive letter C: is reserved for the OS volume. So is there a straightforward way to answer the question - what volume does the Windows OS reside on?. Volume can be a drive letter or a volume GUID or any other way that volumes are identified. Note that I am looking for the OS partition which is not the same as the System partition.

Answer (score 5):

[GetWindowsDirectory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then break up the path with [_splitpath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e737s6tf.aspx).

Edit: Changed GetSystemDirectory with GetWindowsDirectory. In practice results should be the same.